# Firebase Firestore sort collection by ServerTimestamp and with FirebaseUI Firestore Pagination

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

We know that you can use the @ServerTimestamp annotation for an attribute of a document in a collection, for example createdAt (at the time the document is inserted into the collection, the firebase structure automatically assigns the date) and this is an excellent firebase feature. .

However, when it is necessary to get a list of documents from a collection simply sort by createdAt descending:

```
private Query mQuery = mFirestore.collection ("collection"). orderBy
("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

It is also known that it is a bad practice to load data at once into a recyclerview. I found the FirebaseUI adapter that already works with data pagination, it's awesome.

Then the problem arises:
It seems that Firebase Firestore does not work with this static date at the time of "saving" the document, because when returning documents using pagination, the exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. You are trying to
>   start or end a query using a document for which the field 'createdAt'
>   is an uncommitted server timestamp. (Since the value of this field is
>   unknown, you cannot start / end a query with it.)

**The exception is very clear and smart.** However, how to "freeze" the document creation time?

I can not work with local clocks of users, after all, the app will be used in various locations and this "messes" the return of the query. Also, android users can simply set the wrong clock to manipulate results.

Perhaps there could be some "hidden" counter attribute in each document in a specific collection. That would make the job a lot easier, but without doing this manual code-side control.

Has anyone faced this problem? Can you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple, problem-oriented solution was to develop a function in Firebase to return the server date and simply insert it into the collection.

Of course, redoing the wheel, or calling for an enhancement to the Firebase UI component, was not, in my opinion, a smart and workable solution, and coupled with future changes.

In each and every collection that I need to insert, just consult the "moment" and use the result as an attribute.

Simple and effective and does not depend on tweaking of third party component code that works very well.

As a suggestion to the firebase team, put some trigger example that can use the date as simply static attribute at the time of insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore has a way of dealing with server timestamps that have not committed.  DocumentSnapshot has variations of field accessor methods (such as [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior))) that take a [ServerTimestampBehavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.html) enum to indicate what the SDK should take as the value of that server timestamp field.  One of the options is to estimate the value.  I am guessing this makes it possible for a DocumentSnapshot to participate in pagination.

However, it seems that FirebaseUI isn't using these enums.  If this is the case, you'll have to either:

1. Create your own adapter instead of using FirebaseUI
2. Modify the [source of FirebaseUI from GitHub][3] to do what you want
3. File an issue on GitHub and wait to see if it gets implemented.

Comment: Doug thanks for the answer! Is it possible to use a trigger to set a fixed date value in Firebase Firestore? In the Firestore documentation, in the Triggers section, you don't have much detail of what you can and cannot do about dates, modification of documents at recording time, and so on. If I can simply record the date and set it still, but being the server-side "moment", I don't need to make an adapter to handle so many details and complicate the solution.

Comment: In my case, it happens only for first document. After that, everything is smooth. Can you explain it @Doug Stevenson ?